# How to add signup to Vue.js Okta authentication app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, okta

I am building a Vue.js interface that uses Okta for authentication, based on the following: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/02/15/build-crud-app-vuejs-node. I have so far been successful in setting up the router to direct to the default login page with the following method:

```
      login () {
        this.$auth.loginRedirect()
      },
```

However, I want to implement a method and a route that redirects to a signup page. Does Okta for Vue.js include some kind of default signup page? If so, how can I access it? Or would I need to build a signup page from scratch? Thanks.

Comment: I think [these docs](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/eu-self-service.htm) will help

Comment: This helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable User Registration in your Okta dashboard at Users > Registration.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Raible. Could you perhaps also take a look at this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59864935/deploy-vue-js-okta-authentication-app-on-netlify