# Deploy Vue.js Okta Authentication app on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, github, okta, netlify, okta-api

I recently built a Vue.js application with Okta authentication. I am attempting to deploy this application on Netlify. After setting up a new project in Netlify, I imported the Vue.js application into the Netlify project from GitHub. I reconfigured the router in the application so that `redirect_uri` in the Okta initializer reflects the new Netlify URL:

```
import Auth from "@okta/okta-vue";

Vue.use(Auth, {
  issuer: "https://xxx-xxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default",
  client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  redirect_uri: "https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.netlify.com/implicit/callback",
  scope: "openid profile email"
});
```

After deploying the application and clicking the login button, I should be redirected to the default Okta login page. However, I am instead redirected to a page that says "page not found: Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site."

I even made sure to whitelist that URL in my Okta dashboard. Any idea why Netlify doesn't recognize the new redirect_uri? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're deploying a SPA, you need to route all routes to your `index.html` and let Vue handle them.

According to [this article](https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-direct-links-to-my-single-page-app-spa-dont-work/126), you need to add a `_redirects` file to your `publish` directory with the following line to take advantage of browser history pushstate:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

For more info, see [Netlify's docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps).

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks. This solution worked in enabling a redirect to "https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.netlify.com/implicit/callback". However, I am now getting an error message in the console that the redirected URL ```is blocked by CORS policy```. I understand what this policy means, but am not sure why it is blocked. I whitelisted this URL in the Okta dashboard. Will I need to add some kind of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header somewhere in my app to override the block?

Comment: I tried just now to add a ```_headers``` file in the project root, with the line ```/* Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *```, but that still did not work. Am I on the right track though?

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at another Vue.js/Okta issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582551/how-to-set-up-a-callback-route-in-a-vue-js-okta-app

Answer (score 3):

I solved the CORS issue. In the Okta Dashboard, I added the redirecting URL as an original URL under `API > Trusted Origins`. I selected `Add Origin` to specify the base URL of the website, then selected CORS. See : https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/CORS-error-when-accessing-Okta-APIs-from-front-end